# difference between __got section and __nl_symbol_ptr section

Tags: x86-64, mach-o, dynamic-binding, got

Both of them are labeled as *S_NON_LAZY_SYMBOL_POINTERS* and are bound at load time. However, I only see the `__DATA__CONST.__got` section in most Mach-O files.

What's the difference between them and why I can't locate the `__DATA.__nl_symbol_ptr` section?